# In Electrum, is it possible to restore a wallet from seed, from command line?

Tags: electrum

Technically, it should be always possible to restore an Electrum wallet from the seeds.  I know it can be done via GUI, from the New/Restore wizard.

Let's say if we are to put this wallet a machine where GUI is not available, or too cumbersome to set up.  In such case, I wonder if it is possible to restore a wallet from the seeds.

#### Question:

- Is it possible to restore a wallet from seeds at command line?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do

```
electrum restore <seed>
```

You can check what commands are available by doing

```
electrum -h
```

and specific help for a command by doing

```
electrum <cmd> -h
```